# Statements beginning with subject+wonder

Tags: grammaticality, word-order

I'm wondering about the sentence structure when you use *wonder*.

Take for instance:

> I wonder when will my money be refunded.
>
> I wonder when my money will be refunded.
>
> I wonder when is my money going to be refunded.
>
> I wonder when my money is going to be refunded.

Are all these sentences correct or only some of them? By "correct" I mean "grammatically correct".

Could you provide examples of sentences starting with [subject]+*wonder*, and without it while conveying the same idea?

Comment: #2 and #4 are standard. #1 and #3 are nonstandard and would not be tolerated in school or in any edited work; they might be used in speech if they were intoned as quotes or questions, i.e. "I wonder, will will my money be refunded?"

Comment: The only time #1 would be correct is when in a sort of self-reflexive mode you speculate:  "I wonder, when will my money be refunded. I even wonder IF my money will be refunded!" [emphasis on "if"]  Sentence #3 could be modified in similar fashion in a self-reflexive mode, but the resulting construction would be quite rare, I suspect!  I agree with Mitch.  Numbers 2 and 4 are just fine.  There's a Christmas song that goes, "I wonder as I wander out under the sky, how Jesus the Savior did come for to die, for poor orn'ry sinners like you and like I."  ["Orn'ry" denotes meanness, stubbornness.]

Comment: Better on ELL SE.

Answer (score 4):

As @Mitch comments, whilst it's relatively common in casual speech, *I wonder* shouldn't really be followed by an actual question (an [interrogative](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/grammar/overview.html)).

Taking a typical interrogative, such as *who are you*, I don't know the specific grammatical term for the reordered version *who you are*, so I'll just call it a "wh- noun phrase" (which is what you *should* use after *I wonder*). Here's the relevant definition for *wonder* from OED...

> (definition #2) Usually with clause: To ask oneself in wonderment; to feel some doubt or curiosity (how, whether, why, etc.); to be desirous to know or learn.

It's particularly worth noting the following supplementary point made by OED...

> *I wonder* is often placed after a question which expresses the object of curiosity or doubt;
>   e.g. *‘How **can that** be, I wonder?’ = I wonder how **that can** be.*

...where I've highlighted the word-order switch made in that example.

Comment: The use of _wonder_ as a quotative verb **is** recognised by Downing and Locke: 'Mental process verbs which occur as quotatives are few in number in English, in comparison with the wide variety of verbs used in quoted speech. They include _think_, the basic verb, and other verbs of cognition which express some additional, often aspectual, meaning: _muse_, _ponder_, _reflect_, _wonder_.' Quotation marks would not be used to frame these muses, but some form of punctuation should be used after an introductory quotative / quote verb: 'I wonder : / - when will my money be refunded?'

Comment: @Edwin: The fact that *wonder* can be used as a "quotative verb" isn't in dispute. After all, the archetypal such is ***ask***, and exactly the same principle applies: *How **can that** be, I asked?’ = I asked how **that can** be.*

Comment: ...then there's ***my*** favourite "quotative verb" - when people use [go](http://grammar.about.com/od/pq/g/quotativeterm.htm) to mean *said, asked*.

Comment: Are you not tempted by 'be like'?

Comment: @Edwin: ...and Edwin's like, "Aren't you tempted?". But FumbleFingers goes "Nah!".

Answer (score 0):

The sentence structure *I wonder [X]* is declarative. The *X* is usually a noun clause that is the object of the verb *wonder*.

The *X* is treated as a thing, not a question. In the sentence

> I wonder when my money will be refunded

the clause *when my money will be refunded* refers to a discrete concept, a particular defined period of time. Overall, the sentence is not asking a question but observing what the speaker is thinking about.

> I often think about the possible date of my tax refund and how I am going to spend it (although I don't know exactly when that will be).

Because English is a little-declined language, word order is generally used to reflect which terms are the subject and objects (and other forms) in a sentence. The most common word order is subject-verb-object.  To indicate a question, we often reverse the subject-verb order

> I will go to the store.
>
> Will I go to the store?

In examples 1 and 3 in the question, the *when* clause uses the interrogatory structure of verb-subject, *will my money* and *is my money*.

As noted above, the object of *I wonder* is a defined thing, not a question. as such the interrogatory forms are not correct. The declarative forms of 2 and 4 are.

Answer (score 0):

> used in phrases, at the beginning of a request, to make it more formal and polite:  -- Cambridge Dictionary

Ex:

1. We were wondering if/whether you'd like to have dinner with us some time?
2. [ + question word ] I wonder whether you could pass me the butter?
3. I wonder if you could give me some information about places to visit in the area?

From Swan, 278:

- DIRECT: Which is my seat?
- INDIRECT: She wondered which was her seat.
  OR: She wondered which her seat was.