# "I wonder, if I pushed the top of her head, would aerosol spray out of her mouth."

Tags: conditionals, subject-verb-inversion

In Kathryn Stockett's The Help one of the main characters Eugenia "Skeeter" Phelan speculates about mate's hair:

*I wonder, if I pushed the top of her head, **would aerosol** spray out of her mouth.*

Intuitively this sounds just right, but..

Here come my questions:

1. Why **aerosol would** is inverted? To avoid using of two "if"?
   *I wonder if **aerosol would** spray out of her mouth, if I pushed the top of her head.*
2. Is it correct?
3. How to explain this from grammatical point of view?

Kind regards

Comment: The original phrasing is more humorous than what you suggest.

Comment: Compare *If I said you had a beautiful body, **would you** hold it against me?* (highlighted words "inverted" because it's a *question*) and *If I said you had a beautiful body, **you would** hold it against me* (just a *statement*, so no inversion).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, yes! I see the difference. What confused me is that the statement is not a question (I mean direct question). I even checked another edition if it's misprint)

Comment: Found a thread on this (which @FumbleFingers also commented on) https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117698/statements-beginning-with-subjectwonder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the original phrasing, it's posed as a conditional question.  In your version, it's presented as speculation.  Both are correct, but the original one gives more of a "stream of consciousness" feel, more like you'd internally think it rather than if you were writing a research paper on the subject.  Contributing to the humor is the fact that the conjecture about aerosol spraying out of the mouth...the punchline...is saved until the end of the sentence.